# How do I resolve addresses relative to a register in IDA?

Tags: ida, pie

I am reversing an x86 ELF shared object library. Perhaps because of position independence, all functions begin with loading a constant offset into a register:

```
[... function prologue ...]
call    $+5
pop     eax             ; eax = eip = 0x4E2B
add     eax, 1009Dh     ; eax = 0x14EC8 = start of .got.plt section
mov     byte ptr [eax+194h], 0ACh
mov     dword ptr [eax+190h], 968CC5DEh
[...]
```

The first two instructions set `eax` to the current instruction's address. Then a constant offset is added, this offset is probably calculated during linking. 
From there on, all addresses are referenced relative `eax` (in this case, they point into the `.bss` segment).

I can manually calculate all addresses since the value of `eax` is fixed. Is there an automated way to resolve these fixed-register-offsets in IDA, such that IDA can properly resolve X-refs, etc?

Comment: AFAIR One of my colleagues used manticore (https://github.com/trailofbits/manticore) for something like this. Any working symbolic execution engine should also fit.